# Excel VBA won't work on cells with leading zeros

Tags: vba, excel

My task is to take a specific subset of serial numbers, write a replacement, and run a find & replace on larger set of serial numbers. What I have so far is:

```
Sub multiFindandReplace()
  Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, cel As Range
  Set myList = Sheets("Replacement Data").Range("B2:C4246")     
  'two column range with find/replace pairs 
  Set myRange = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("B2:B20000") 
  'range to be searched and replace 
  For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
    myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole 
  Next cel
End Sub
```

The code only works on entries with no leading zeroes. I need to keep the leading zeroes, but the problem is that the serial numbers in the master data list do not all begin with zeros, so they are not all being replaced, and are of different lengths.

I've attached a snippet of sample data below:

```
Part #  Full Part #
4184    004184
4444    004444
100001  00100001
100002  00100002
100003  00100003
100004  00100004
100005  00100005
100006  00100006
100007  00100007
100008  00100008
```

This find/replace list is 2000 rows. I need to search a list of 20,000 items and replace these 2000 rows.

Comment: You have not set myRange or Cel.

Comment: Is that all the code? It looks like you are wanting a loop, as there's `Next cel` at the end of the `.Replace` line...Did you maybe forget to add the loop too? (`For each cel in MyList`?)  Edit: Ah, there it is.  Do you need VBA? Does a formula `=If(left(A2,2)<>"00","'00"&A2,"")` not do the trick?

Comment: It is the complete code. This runs correctly on my files, as long as the cells don't contain a leading zero. I suspect the problem is not with the code, but maybe an additional setting in excel that will enable me to use this on cells of all types?

Comment: I added this line: myRange.NumberFormat = "@" but my target data still remains unchanged after running. I changed all data columns to text format prior to running, is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the range format to text before populating:

```
Sub multiFindandReplace()
  Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, cel As Range
  Set myList = Sheets("Replacement Data").Range("B2:C4246")     
  'two column range with find/replace pairs 
  Set myRange = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("B2:B20000") 
      myRange.NumberFormat = "@"  'this line should force text format and stop Excel removing the leading zeros
  'range to be searched and replace 
  For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
    myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole 
  Next cel
End Sub
```